# Apache solr verifying query before executing it on solr

Tags: php, solr

I am using php and solr, problem I am facing is that whenever query is built dynamically there are sometimes situations where query does not have proper syntax or proper parameters passed.

As a result I am getting error in solr logs.

I need a solution so that queries with syntax errors should not be executed by the application.

Answer (score 0):

Your Solr library should handle everything for you - escaping where escaping is needed, etc. If you're building the URL yourself, you'll [have to escape the values](http://e-mats.org/2010/01/escaping-characters-in-a-solr-query-solr-url/) that [Solr expects to be escaped](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/master/solr/solrj/src/java/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/util/ClientUtils.java#L158), and properly urlencode the values as needed.

Here's the list from the ClientUtils link above:

```
  // These characters are part of the query syntax and must be escaped
  if (c == '\\' || c == '+' || c == '-' || c == '!'  || c == '(' || c == ')' || c == ':'
    || c == '^' || c == '[' || c == ']' || c == '\"' || c == '{' || c == '}' || c == '~'
    || c == '*' || c == '?' || c == '|' || c == '&'  || c == ';' || c == '/'
    || Character.isWhitespace(c)) {
```